# Where can I get the update site for Spring tool suite

Tags: eclipse, spring, eclipse-plugin, spring-tool-suite

Actually I am trying to install spring tool suit for eclipse Kepler(4.3) from eclipse marketplace  but I am getting the following error

communication with repository at http://dist.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/update/e4.3 failed

Is there any other repository from where I can install STS(Spring Tool Suite)

Thanks and Regards
Vishal

Answer (score 9):

Check out  [this url](http://dist.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/update/e4.3/compositeContent.xml). If it doesn't work (**AccessDenied**) then you have network problems.

If it works it's OK; **the STS will work by giving this URL**: http://dist.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/update/3.4.0.RELEASE/e4.3/

**(Help -> Install new software -> work with : *the URL here*)**

BTW, it took me 5 days of searching :-)

Comment: Thanks for posting this! For some reason I can't fathom, this information is both useful and tricky to find.

Answer (score 1):

You will find here: https://spring.io/tools/sts/all
the installation version of the integrated eclipse STS,
along with both eclipse update site urls, 
and archived version it.

Previous Spring Tool Suite versions are also [referenced](https://spring.io/tools/sts/legacy).

Comment: The  folowing eclipse update site urls found at first provided link seems to still respond ... Eclipse 4.16: https://download.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/sts4/update/e4.16/
Eclipse 4.15: https://download.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/sts4/update/e4.15/
Eclipse 4.14: https://download.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/sts4/update/e4.14/

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays all update sites are mentioned at https://github.com/spring-projects/sts4/wiki/Installation.
Note it's STS 4 only. Not sure where to find up-do-date STS 3 update sites, although I know this one is still working: https://download.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/update/3.9.12.RELEASE/e4.15/

In general, this page is still working and lists all STS 3 releases: https://dist.springsource.com/release/STS/index.html
The correct update site URL can be crafted by looking into full dist URLs - the aforementioned one still looks to be the latest.

Answer (score 0):

If the marketplace isn't working, your best bet is to pull down the complete package from [here](http://www.springsource.org/downloads/sts-ggts).

Answer (score 0):

The proper eclipse update URL for JUNO version :

```
http://dist.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/update/e4.4/
```